# How to improve this function?

Tags: scala, collections

Suppose I've got a data structure like that:

```
case class B(bx: Int)
case class A(ax: Int, bs: Seq[B])
```

I am writing a function `A => Seq[(Int, Option[Int])]` as follows:

```
def foo(a: A): Seq[(Int, Option[Int])] = 
  if (a.bs.isEmpty) Seq((a.ax, None)) else a.bs.map(b => (a.ax, Some(b.bx)))
```

It seems working but I don't like the branching. How would you improve `foo` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option - add an auxiliary function that takes a `Seq[T]` and returns a `Seq[Option[T]]` where the output is *never empty* - if the input is empty, the output would have a single `None` element in its result:

```
def foo(a: A): Seq[(Int, Option[Int])] = toOptions(a.bs.map(_.bx)).map((a.ax, _))

// always returns a non-empty list - with None as the only value for empty input
def toOptions[T](s: Seq[T]): Seq[Option[T]] = s.headOption +: s.drop(1).map(Some(_))
```

Benefits:

- This *truly* has no branching (including `getOrElse` which is a kind of branching, albeit a more elegant one)
- No repetition of building the tuple (`a.ax` called once)
- Nice separation of concerns (building a never-empty list vs. dealing with A and Bs)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Option` companion object to compose.

```
def foo(a: A): Seq[(Int, Option[Int])] = 
  Option(a.bs).filterNot(_.isEmpty)
              .map(list => list.map(b => (a.ax, Some(b.bx))))
              .getOrElse(Seq((a.ax, None)))
```

Comment: do you really consider this code better than the original ?

Comment: Thats lets to the user to decide @volia17