# How to convert nested sequences to a sequence of tuples?

Tags: scala, collections

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722343/how-to-improve-this-function).

Suppose I've got a data structure like that now:

```
case class C()

case class B(cs: Seq[C])

case class A(bs: Seq[B])
```

How would you write a function `A => Seq[(A, Option[B], Option[C])]` ?
The function should work like that:

```
A(Nil)              // Seq((Some(A()), None, None))
A(Seq(B(Nil)))      // Seq((Some(A()), Some(B()), None))
A(Seq(B(Seq(C())))) // Seq((Some(A()), Some(B()), Some(C()))
```

Would a monad transformer be useful in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you need - basing this on a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50723110/5344058) to a similar question:

```
def foo(a: A): Seq[(A, Option[B], Option[C])] =
  toOptions(a.bs).flatMap(optB =>
    optB
      .map(b => toOptions(b.cs))
      .getOrElse(Seq(None))
      .map(optC => (a, optB, optC))
  )

// always returns a non-empty list - with None as the only value for empty input
def toOptions[T](s: Seq[T]): Seq[Option[T]] = s.headOption +: s.drop(1).map(Some(_))
```

Comment: I think there is a small bug in this code. I guess `.getOrElse(Seq())` should be replaced with `.getOrElse(Seq(None))`. Is it correct ?

Comment: Oh, that's absolutely right, I'll edit to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic `map`/`flatMap` combination with an extra test for the `None` condition.

```
def unwind(a:A) :Seq[(A, Option[B], Option[C])] = {
  if (a.bs.isEmpty) Seq((a,None,None))
  else a.bs.flatMap{ b =>
    if (b.cs.isEmpty) Seq((a,Some(b),None))
    else b.cs.map(c => (a,Some(b),Some(c)))
  }
}
```